# Storing a collection into a list and session - Front End

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have this program in which I am trying to store a collection of values into a list and session

Example:

```
valueCollection = (List<Values>)Session["Value"];
```

I want to do the front end in a way which will show a table with each row showing a label and textbox. This would be too simple to do obviously but I want it to show 4 rows of the table by default and then the user can select "add another" this will then add another row onto the table with a label and textbox exactly similar to the 4 default. Everytime the user selects "add another" the table increments by 1.

How do you do something like that, or is there an easy way?

Here is a screenshot to explain it better:
http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/9986/idead.png

Comment: is this a web based application? are you planning on doing this via ajax (asynchronously) or using postbacks?

Comment: It is a web based application using a wizard (stepbystep) this is the second step. I have the AjaxControlToolkit and may use the toolkitscriptmanager or postbacks, I just need a way of how to approach this

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that you bind a control to your data and provide GUI controls to allow users to add/edit/delete records. Once the records are modified you re-bind the control to see the changes.

Take a look at the [Databound controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx) in the .Net Framework. For a quick first pass you could use a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) - a control which provides built-in functionality to automatically generate and mange the add/edit/delete GUI elements.

In 'real world' usage, storing big datasets isn't a great idea as more users = more sessions and each session uses server resources. You should really be getting/storing your data in a database or perhaps an XML file.

HTH